# How can I globally add methods to JSON, Date or other 'native' objects in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

*I know that doing that is bad, but still.*

I have a module with utilities I often use.
Inside it, if I declare, for example,

```
JSON.foo = function(){return "Hi!";};
```

then the JSON.foo method will be available, but only inside the module.

How can I make it available from outside the module, where I require it?

i.e.

```
var utils = require("utils");
console.log(JSON.foo()); // "Hi!"
```

Comment: I really hope that there is no way of doing that.

Comment: It ends up being a mystery where the extended object functionality is coming from with this style. Not sure why you wouldn't use `utils.foo()`?

Comment: its a bad practice but maybe its what you want, declare it globally, like GLOBAL.JSON = JSON

Comment: @WiredPrairie I think that it's really awkward that JSON.parse throws an exception in case of error input, instead of passing an error object (which suits async nodejs code better), so I want to implement a custom tryParse method, which naturally belongs to JSON.
Please, feel free to correct me, if I am deeply wrong somewhere, because nodejs is quite new to me.

Comment: It's just my opinion that I don't care for functions to be added to other objects without a clear source, especially in a team of developers. It's also a bit-anti-pattern for NodeJS. `utils.tryParseJson()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**utils.js**

```
JSON.foo = function(){return "Hi!";};
exports.JSON = JSON
```

**usesUtils.js**

```
var utils = require("./utils");
console.log(JSON.foo()); // "Hi!"
```